# BCP - Invalid character value for cast specification when importing to table with IDENTITY column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am trying to load a file from UNIX to SQL Server. When I run the BCP getting the error below, but I was able to load the same file when I changed the datatype to Char.

Command used:

**--`bcp  [SQLAAA].[APP_XXX].[ACTIVITY_V1]  in /home/XXX_ACTIVITY.txt -c  -S xddb001 -e /home/ERRORS.log -t "|" -r "\n"    -U test12 -P test12`**

Source file:

```
222|2017-12-27|Y|ABC|2017-12-27|ABC|2017-12-27
255|2018-01-04|N|ABC|2018-01-04|ABC|2018-01-04
```

Error Message:

> @ Row 1, Column 7: Invalid character value for cast specification @

Definition table:

```
CREATE TABLE [APP_XX].[ACTIVITY]
(
[C1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[C2_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
[c3] [varchar](1) NULL,
[C4_NM] [varchar](10) NULL,
[C5_DTM] [date] NULL,
[C6_NM] [varchar](10) NULL,
[C7_DTM] [date] NULL,
[ROW_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Could you please let me know what modification can be done?

Comment: The rows you have pasted in your question do not have all | symbols as separators. Also, we do not know what your destination table definition is. Please specify this table definition, otherwise we would just be guessing. Aside from that, when importing with `BCP IN` it is best to do an import based on a format file. So first create a format file for your destination table (`BCP FORMAT`), then use that format file in your import statement.

Comment: Here is the Source file.  
222|2017-12-27|Y|ABC|2017-12-27|ABC|2017-12-27
255|2018-01-04|N|ABC|2018-01-04|ABC|2018-01-04

 
**DDL**

CREATE TABLE [APP_XX].[ACTIVITY]
(
[C1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[C2_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
[c3] [varchar](1) NULL,
[C4_NM] [varchar](10) NULL,
[C5_DTM] [date] NULL,
[C6_NM] [varchar](10) NULL,
[C7_DTM] [date] NULL,
[ROW_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Add that information in your question please, use the edit link underneath your question to do so. Or click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48197065/edit) <- here.

Comment: Finally i was able to load the file using BCP to DATE fields after taking off  IDENTITY Field from table.   if i add Identity field ROW_NUM  again i will get a error as " Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification"   ...... I am using BCP  --bcp  [SQLDB].[APP_XX].[LOAD_ACTIVITY]  in /home/LOAD_ACTIVITY.txt  -c  -S wdSERVER1 -e /home/ERRORS.log -t "|" -r "\n"    -U test -P XXX.  Could you please help  what  switch should be used to remove the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing into a table with an IDENTITY column, and you do not supply values for the IDENTITY column in the import file, you need to specify in a format file that the IDENTITY column will be skipped in the import.

This way of working is explicitely mentioned in the [Microsoft documentation on BCP, flag -E](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#E):

> If the data file does not contain values for the identity column in the table or view, use a format file to specify that the identity column in the table or view should be skipped when importing data; SQL Server automatically assigns unique values for the column.[...]

What you need to do:

1. First [create a format file using BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server). E.g. for a non-XML format file, the command looks like `BCP table_or_view format nul -f format_file_name`
2. Specify to skip the IDENTITY column in the format file
3. Use the format file you created in your `BCP IN` command using the [BCP `-f` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#f)

Comment: Many thanks for your solution.  I have created format file and able to load Identity field.  You saved me:)

Comment: For what it's worth. This exact situation can also occur if the definitions of the output and input do not match.