# BCP Invalid character for cast specification

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlbulkcopy, sql-server-2017

I am trying to import the CSV with these contents into my SQL server database.

The data :

```
tranche_d_age
<18
18_24
25_34
35_44
45_60
>60
```

The format file :

```
14.0
1
1       SQLCHAR             0       0      "\n"   2     tranche_d_age_id                                      French_CI_AS
```

In the database, I created a table with the following specifications :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[ref_tranches_age]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ref_tranches_age](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tranche_d_age_id] [varchar](max) NULL
)
GO
```

Here is the bcp command I issue:

```
bcp [xxx].dbo.tranches_age in 'ref_tranches_age.csv' -U 'xxx' -P 'xxx' -S 'xxx' -f bcp_ref_tranches_age.fmt
```

And the response:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 22
```

Seems to me that the response contains 7 error messages for 7 lines in the csv file. (I might be wrong)

I found these 2 threads saying I shouldn't have blanks in my source file & I shouldn't insert into the identity column. Which, unless I'm wrong, I am not doing.

- [Thread 1: Identity column specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197065/bcp-invalid-character-value-for-cast-specification-when-importing-to-table-wit)
- [Thread 2: Blanks specification](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98f22137-caac-42e4-a229-c9629c957262/invalid-character-value-for-cast-specification?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Why is `[tranche_d_age_id]` a `varchar(MAX)`? The longest string in your sample data is 5 characters long. Do you really have an age range with 2,147,483,648 characters?

Comment: Have you tried using "\r\n" as the terminator?

Comment: @Owen Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Larnu I used bcp with varchar(max) before, do you think it poses a problem here?

Comment: Do you know which character it objects to? e.g. if you remove the first and last lines does it work?

Comment: My point is that a `varchar(MAX)` is for storing very large pieces of text (up to 2GB). Your data is only about 5 characters long so there's no need for it to be a `varchar(MAX)`. It's like using a `decimal(38,0)` to store a bit value.

Comment: @Larnu, I understand. But this is a Varchar, which doesn't store that many characters, it only takes in the number of bytes necessary to hold the string it stores. Am I wrong? Also, without going into further details, this whole table is temporary. I agree with you that it isn't a great practice, but it isn't exactly the problem at hand.

Comment: @Owen, I edited the question to take into account the bcp call and the returned result.

Comment: That isn't quite true, @Aetos. You should only use a `MAX` datatype if you're going to need to store more than 8000/4000 characters, otherwise stick to a size that is **relevant** for the data. A `MAX` datatype is stored differently to one that isn't. You can't index `MAX` datatypes in the same way either, and performing a `JOIN` on them can have some awful performance impacts. Use a length, precision and scale that is representative of your data. You don't need over 2b illion characters for an age range, so don't use a datatype that can. In the case, use a `varchar(5)` seems appropriate.

Comment: Aetos - 1st - the data you've pasted into your post has crlf as the line terminator. That might just be what SO does when you paste in text, but it would be good to directly confirm if your data is terminated with \n as you stated or with \r\n as it appears in what you shared; similarly, what you've pasted in does not have a line terminator on the last row. 2nd - Try using the -e option. This will give you a nice glimpse at the data as BCP is seeing it. Yes, you are getting an error for each of the lines you are trying to import and so when you use -e you should get a error file with 7 errors.

Comment: I tested and your sample works for me. Im on SQL 2014 and using different collation, but I doubt those are having anything to do with it. That leaves your actual data file. I create mine here from copy/past of your post above, so I used \r\n, but also tried with \n.. both worked. Can you view your file with a good text editor and inspect the actual line terminator? Windows notepad wont do... need an editor that can fully show white space characters. Notepad++, UltraEdit, etc... You can also look at the error file with a good editor too for some clues.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the file ref_tranches_age.csv it is possible that it contains lineterminator = '\ r \ n' as a line separator and the file bcp_ref_tranches_age.fmt specifies lineterminator = '\ n'. So you have two options, the first is that when creating your csv file you specify that the lineterminator = '\ n' and voila, or else in your bcp_ref_tranches_age.fmt file you add lineterminator = '\ r \ n' as follows way:

```
bcp [xxx] .dbo.tranches_age in 'ref_tranches_age.csv' -U 'xxx' -P 'xxx' -S 'xxx' -f bcp_ref_tranches_age.fmt -r "\ r \ n"
```

then the .fmt file will look something like this:

```
14.0 
1 
1 
SQLCHAR     0   0   "\r\n"  2   tranche_d_age_id French_CI_AS
```